# Quick Access Toolbar - Customize Shortcut keys

Tags: xml, excel, vba, ribbon, ribbonx

How can I customize the shortcut keys in the Quick Access Toolbar of Microsoft Excel?  For example, instead of the first icon in the Quick Access Toolbar being activated by `Alt 1`, I'd like it to be `Alt S`.  I understand that this may requires XML, and I'm looking for an example of code.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. You can do it with macros in the Personal.xlsb, but that feels dirty.